# GoogleMap OnCameraChangeListener GeoCoder AsynTask Block UI Thread for 30 seconds

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-asynctask

*Code That handle map surfing by finger but sometime UI thread is blocked for nearly 30 seconds before entering to execute Async task Code*

```
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
            ShowSearchLocationLoader(true);
            LatLng latlngCamera = new LatLng(cameraPosition.target.latitude, cameraPosition.target.longitude);

            if(Utilities.isConnected == true) {
                cameraChangedTask = new CameraChangedTask();
                cameraChangedTask.execute(latlngCamera);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ActivityHome.this, R.string.connection_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    });
}
```

---

```
private class CameraChangedTask extends AsyncTask<LatLng, Void, Void> {
       List<Address> address;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(LatLng... latLngs) {
            Geocoder coder = new Geocoder(currentContext);
            LatLng location = latLngs[0];
            try {
                    address = coder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, 1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); // getFromLocation() may sometimes fail
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            try {

                if (address != null) {
                    if (address.isEmpty()) {
                        mAutocompleteView.setHint("Waiting for Location");
                    } else {
                        if (address.size() > 0 && address.get(0) != null) {
                            mAutocompleteView.setHint(address.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.get(0).getAddressLine(1));
                            setPickupaddress(address.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.get(0).getAddressLine(1));
                        } else {
                            mAutocompleteView.setHint(address.get(0).getFeatureName());
                            setPickupaddress(address.get(0).getFeatureName());
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ShowSearchLocationLoader(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Solution to my problem is here:                                 cameraChangedTask = new CameraChangedTask();
cameraChangedTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,latlngCamera);   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168693/asynctasks-blocking-others

Answer (score 0):

cameraChangedTask = new CameraChangedTask();
                              cameraChangedTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,latlngCamera);